# Can someone explain how I can triangulate using angles and one side of a Right-angled triangle?

Tags: geometry, education, triangulation, angle

I've been looking around, trying to find a simple way explaining why and how to calculate distance using the triangulation technique, but I'm still pretty confused, I've got some simple math notions, but I lack knowledge on using angles to solve such problems.
I have a simple example, and I'd like to solve it using triangulation.

Any help is appreciated!

P.S.: I'm a layman at math, so I'm sorry in advance.

> **Triangle specifications:**
>
> A side: Unknown
>
> B side: 10 meters
>
> C(hypotenuse): Unknown
>
> AB angle: 90°
>
> BC angle: 70°

**UPDATE:**

After some searching, I found a website that clarifies:

*Cos, Sin, Tan*

https://www.mathsisfun.com/sine-cosine-tangent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have drawn your triangle, but the sides are named with lower case letters instead of capitals thanks to Geogebra.  Side $a$ is $10 \tan (70^\circ)$ , then you can get $c$ from either $c=\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$ or $c=\frac {10}{\cos (70^\circ)}$  If you have a right angle, finding the coordinates of $B$ is pretty easy. If you don't, you need to solve a pair of simultaneous equations that represent the lengths from A to B and C to B
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ross, but I'm still a little bit confused on how to calculate it, May you go step-by-step solving the problem

Comment: Do you know the definitions of the trig functions and understand those formulas?  What coordinates are you given?  Are you trying to find the coordinates of B?

Comment: The length of B is given as 10 meters in your problem.  I showed how to compute the lengths of the other two sides.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the length of `a`

Comment: In a right triangle, the tangent of an angle is defined as the opposite side divided by the adjacent side, so $\tan 70^\circ = a/b$  That is where I got $a=10 \tan 70^\circ$, but substituting in $b=10$

Comment: I don't know how to solve a = 10 **tan70°**, I don't know how to treat *tan70°*

Comment: It is a constant.  You can compute it approximately on a calculator, if you set it to degree mode.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan+%2870+degrees%29) tells us that $\tan 70^\circ \approx 2.7475$, so $a \approx 27.475$

Comment: Thank you so much for paying attention, and helping me

Answer (score 1):

A good acronym that we teach in the US is "soh cah toa," which is a made-up Native American word.  You can interpret it as

- s = o/h, which means sin(angle) = "opposite side" over "hypotenuse"
- c = a/h, which means cos(angle) = "adjacent side" over "hypotenuse"
- t = o/a, which means tan(angle) = "opposite side" over "adjacent side"

In your case, the side $A$ is opposite the angle BC.  I recommend you draw a picture to convince yourself that $\tan(70) = \frac{A}{B}$, and therefore $A = (10 {{\rm m}}) \times \tan(70^\circ \times (\frac{\pi {{\rm rad}}}{180^\circ} ) )$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Charles +1, So it's PI times radians, where do I get the radians? I'm pretty ignorant I'm sorry

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton Actually, I would recommend you just write $\tan(70^\circ)$ if your instructor is OK with it (and I guess they probably are, since they gave you all the angles in degrees in the first place). If you are supposed to use "pure" trig functions, using only a number of radians as their input (for example, many math libraries for computer programs require this), you can write $\tan\left(70 \times \frac{\pi}{180}\right)$; you might consider $\frac{\pi}{180}$ as a "conversion factor" that converts degrees to radians.

Comment: I don't have any instructor, I did it at home, I found the angle by using a protractor :)